# Windows 8.1 multiple instances of Windows Store app

Tags: manifest, windows-8.1, multiple-instances, windows-store

one of the promises of Windows 8.1 is the possibility of multiple instance of Windows Store Apps.

But I'm not finding how to activate this.

I've found the  element of the app manifest

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn423281.aspx

But I don't know what to add in the ?? values:

```
<Package xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/2010/manifest" xmlns:m2="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/2013/manifest">
  <Extensions>
    <Extension Category="windows.activatableClass.outOfProcessServer">
      <OutOfProcessServer ServerName="??">
        <Path>??</Path>
        <Instancing>multipleInstances</Instancing>
        <ActivatableClass ActivatableClassId="MyApp.App"/>
      </OutOfProcessServer>
    </Extension>
  </Extensions>
</Package>
```

Could you help me to activate multiple instances of my application?

Thank you a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each app can have a single instance but multiple views - each view runs in its own thread.  Here is an [example](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Multiple-Views-Sample-2582fcf3) on MSDN.  I wrote [an article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/synergist/archive/2013/10/25/using-new-windowing-feature-in-windows-8-1.aspx) about how I added multiple views to an app.

Comment: That works!!!
The sample is not as simple as I imagine, but in the end it works.

Thank you very much!
ps: I've downloading Zoetrope :D Great job!

Comment: Thank you - any feedback and rating on Zoetrope would be appreciated.

Comment: can you tell me how to run multiple instances of windows phone 8.1 emulator? Also the article link seems to be broken

Answer (score 0):

Right click on your project and select unload project.
Right click on your project and select edit .csproj
On the XML view find `<ProjectGuid>` tag.
Generate a new GUID and replace it.
Right click on your project reload it.

Go to Package.appxmanifest and change 
Application tab Display name
Visual assets Short name
Packaging Package name

Then create the app package and then install it via powershell.

Each time you need to deploy a new instance of the same app, do above.